Is there any way to run the Android Emulator (from Visual Studio Community 2022) on a Windows 11 Home Edition machine?
Problem:
My Windows 11 Home PC cannot run the Android Emulator.
The Android Emulator window opens, but it doesn't load the Android OS.
What I've Tried:

I have already enabled Intel VT-x in the BIOS.
I manually tried to install Intel HAXM on Windows, but I receive an error stating that Intel HAXM cannot be installed on my computer.
I have confirmed that my system meets all the necessary hardware requirements.


Any particular error message? What image are you trying to run?

it does not have a message but the emulator displays only black screen and not started the android OS that is supposed to.

Ok, but again: What is the name of the image you're trying to run? You need to choose an X64 image, not an Arm image.

x86_64, i think that's the default image since installing vs studio.
